# How to use the events?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm just discovering jquery-mobile, but I find the documentation not really adapted to "beginners".

So, I have a fieldset with some radiobutton. When the user "check" a button, how to do to save the value in a php session with an ajax call ?

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
  <legend>Choose a pet:</legend>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" checked="checked" />
  <label for="radio-choice-1">Cat</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-2" value="choice-2"  />
  <label for="radio-choice-2">Dog</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-3" value="choice-3"  />
  <label for="radio-choice-3">Hamster</label>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-choice-1" id="radio-choice-4" value="choice-4"  />
  <label for="radio-choice-4">Lizard</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets start simpler with a jQuery example, how familiar are you with jQuery?

You'll need to bind a handler to the change event on the radio button, then fire an AJAX call to PHP where you set the session variable.

To bind a handler see jQuery docs for the `on` or `live` function, something like in a `$(document).ready...`

```
$('input[name="radio-choice-1"]').live('change', function(){
    var value = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
         //see jQuery ajax functions
    });
});
```

**But on jQuery Mobile:**

You should be using the pageinit event of jQM (jQuery Mobile) to run this code not document.ready, if you're using multiple single-page-templates and ajax transitions even more so - in which case then you should also be using the `on` function instead of live in order to listen to bubbled events for the current page only.

Then it'll be akin to

`$('#yourPage').on('change', 'input[name="radio-choice-1"]', function(){`

Comment: Your input on jQuery Mobile helped and is really a trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

U need to bind a change handler and fire an ajax call as follows

```
$('input[name="radio-choice-1"]').live('change', function(){
var selectedValue = $(this).val();

 $.post("save.php", {optionSelected: selectedValue});
});
```

where save.php contents would be

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['radio-choice-1-option'] = $_POST['optionSelected'];
?>
```

Comment: Ok, it's similar to jQuery in fact